# Count number of characters in a string, create a data frame column out of it?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, count

A quick question for the universe of programmers.

DATA. Data frame column consisting of names.

```
g['NAME']=['John', 'Michael', 'Jezus', 'Donald', 'Suzy']
```

DESIRED RESULT. Another, parallel data frame column consisting of number of characters in for each name in g['NAME'].

```
g['NAME_count'] = [4,7,5,6,4]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use vectorised [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html#pandas.Series.str.len) to achieve this:

```
In [106]:
df['NAME_Count'] = df['NAME'].str.len()
df

Out[106]:
      NAME  NAME_Count
0     John           4
1  Michael           7
2    Jezus           5
3   Donald           6
4     Suzy           4
```